# Serverless framework deploying without credentials in docker container

Tags: docker, serverless-framework

I created a docker container, put my project inside it and then I ran `sls deploy` and it worked even without to setup credentials. How is it possible? Is Serverless Framework getting the credentials from memory or anywhere else?

[image]

Comment: Could you share how did you run the deployment previously? Did you pass the access key explicitly as env vars by any chance?

Comment: Yeah @Progress1ve in my local I ran the deploy with env. You mean that the container is accessing my local env rather than inner env?

Comment: Hey @Jeff Pal, it's hard to answer based on how you've actually setup and run the container in the first place. If you could provide reproduction steps it would make it easier to reason about it.

Answer (score 0):

During serverless deploy, it can get config information from ~/.aws/credentials file. There is an explanation about it in the document https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials/